# Rails activerecord attributes=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am doing this:

```
@person.attributes = params[:person]
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to why doing an attributes= would cause a bunch of SQL to show in my logs?

I see a couple of SELECT and even an UPDATE.

I swear I am not doing a "save" -- so I have no idea why setting attributes would trigger queries.

Is there a before_ of after_ filter I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have behaviour that's triggered on assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting attributes on a standard model does not cause any `SELECT` or `UPDATE` calls as far as I am aware. This is further seen to be true when I run log concurrently with a *script/console* session:

```
>> f = Forum.first

==> ./log/development.log <==
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
  Forum Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `forums` ORDER BY title asc LIMIT 1
  Forum Columns (12.6ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `forums`
=> #<Forum id: 1, title: "Welcome to rBoard!", description: "This is an example forum for Rboard.", is_visible_to_id: nil, topics_created_by_id: nil, position: 1, parent_id: nil, last_post_id: 1, last_post_forum_id: nil, topics_count: 1, posts_count: 4, category_id: nil, active: true, open: true>
>> f.attributes
=> {"position"=>1, "is_visible_to_id"=>nil, "open"=>true, "topics_count"=>1, "title"=>"Welcome to rBoard!", "last_post_forum_id"=>nil, "posts_count"=>4, "id"=>1, "category_id"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil, "topics_created_by_id"=>nil, "last_post_id"=>1, "description"=>"This is an example forum for Rboard.", "active"=>true}
>> f.attributes = _
=> {"position"=>1, "is_visible_to_id"=>nil, "open"=>true, "topics_count"=>1, "title"=>"Welcome to rBoard!", "last_post_forum_id"=>nil, "posts_count"=>4, "id"=>1, "category_id"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil, "topics_created_by_id"=>nil, "last_post_id"=>1, "description"=>"This is an example forum for Rboard.", "active"=>true}
```

You can see here that there is only two SQL queries that get executed, one to fetch the `Forum` record and the other to find out what columns are on the `forums` table.

It is not until I save it that it does some queries:

```
>> f.attributes
=> {"position"=>1, "is_visible_to_id"=>nil, "open"=>true, "topics_count"=>1, "title"=>"Welcome to rBoard!", "last_post_forum_id"=>nil, "posts_count"=>4, "id"=>1, "category_id"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil, "topics_created_by_id"=>nil, "last_post_id"=>1, "description"=>"This is an example forum for Rboard.", "active"=>true}
>> attr = _
=> {"position"=>1, "is_visible_to_id"=>nil, "open"=>true, "topics_count"=>1, "title"=>"Welcome to rBoard!", "last_post_forum_id"=>nil, "posts_count"=>4, "id"=>1, "category_id"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil, "topics_created_by_id"=>nil, "last_post_id"=>1, "description"=>"This is an example forum for Rboard.", "active"=>true}
>> attr["position"] = 2
=> 2
>> f.save
  SQL (0.2ms)   BEGIN
=> true
>>   SQL (0.2ms)   COMMIT
f.attributes = attr
=> {"position"=>2, "is_visible_to_id"=>nil, "open"=>true, "topics_count"=>1, "title"=>"Welcome to rBoard!", "last_post_forum_id"=>nil, "posts_count"=>4, "id"=>1, "category_id"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil, "topics_created_by_id"=>nil, "last_post_id"=>1, "description"=>"This is an example forum for Rboard.", "active"=>true}
>> WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: id
f.save
  SQL (0.2ms)   BEGIN
  Forum Update (20.3ms)   UPDATE `forums` SET `position` = 2 WHERE `id` = 1
  SQL (27.2ms)   COMMIT
=> true
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I found out it was because we have custom extensions that overwrote the basic attributes= method. :(. But thanks for your in depth answer.